# How do I tell Cargo to check a local directory for a replacement dependency and use it?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to understand how to change a broken dependency in Rust. I cloned the code from GitHub and updated the dependencies in the Cargo.toml so it can compile, but how do I use it in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Cargo documentation on overriding a dependency](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#overriding-dependencies):

> Cargo looks for a directory named `.cargo` up the directory hierarchy of your project [...] To specify overrides, create a `.cargo/config` file in some ancestor of your project’s directory [...] Inside that file, put this:
>
> ```
> paths = ["/path/to/project"]
> ```
>
> This array should be filled with directories that contain a `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Thank you! Specifically I created a `.cargo` one level up, with a file called `config` that has `paths = ["./project"]` with the project being in the ancestor directory containing the `.cargo` file.